# Socket.io - Unable to get the number of clients in room

Tags: javascript, socket.io

```
const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = 3000;
var numClients = {};


server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.get('/room1', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/room1.html');
});

app.get('/room2', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/room2.html');
});

app.get('/room3', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/room3.html');
});



// tech namespace
const tech = io.of('/tech');

tech.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('join', (data) =>{
        socket.join(data.room)
        console.log(numClients[data.room]);
        if (numClients[data.room] == undefined) {
            numClients[data.room] = 1;
        } else {
        numClients[data.room]++;
        }
        console.log(numClients[data.room]);
        //emittig message to people in room

        tech.in(data.room).emit('message', `New user joined ${data.room} room!`)
    })


    socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
        numClients[data.room]--;

        tech.emit('message', 'user disconnected');
    })
})
```

Whenever a person joins a room, the numClients[data.room] number increases by 1. But when a person leaves the room the numClients[data.room] number should decrease but it does not for some reason. Instead, the number does not change at all. How do I fix this?

Comment: You track disconnection but not leave. Have you tried something like `socket.on('leave', () => {numClients[data.room]--;});`? In your example, you never call `socket.leave()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the code where your user leaves. So your users **never leave the room** except when they disconnect (e.g. close the browser).

You should handle this case as you do for joining:

```
socket.on('leave', (data) =>{
    socket.leave(data.room, () => {
        console.log(numClients[data.room]);
        numClients[data.room]--;
        console.log(numClients[data.room]);

        //emittig message to people in room
        tech.in(data.room).emit('message', `User left ${data.room} room!`)
    });
});
```

Now, if user disconnects after leaving, make sure you don't decrement `numClients` again!

To be on the safe side, I'd suggest `numClients[data.room]` be a list of users that joined, instead of a number. So you count your users with `Object.keys(numClients[data.room]).length`.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your help! I added your code in, however, now it doesn't log the messages in the console and the number of clients still remains unchanged